# How to retain all columns in pandas while using regex

Tags: regex, pandas

There are around more than 100 columns with first two columns as primary keys.

As per screenshot, Col A and B are primary keys and we need to find out all the columns having "cad" in their names and then convert those column into "usd" by multiplying them 0.75. Also, the column names should be renamed from "cad" to "usd"

[image]

I used following code to do multiplication but output of this code does not give me other columns like id1, id2, name, age, add, unit etc.

df=df.filter(regex='cad')*0.75

df.columns= [c.replace('cad','usd') for c in df.columns]

Output should look like :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cad_cols = df.filter(regex='cad').columns
df[cad_cols] *= 0.75
df.columns= [c.replace('cad','usd') for c in df.columns]
```